# MySQL PHP - Fetch data and present in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, fetch

I'm just learning PHP and I'd like to do a basic login. Once logged in, I'd like to show basic information from the user (in this example, just the name), but for some reason I'm not getting the name printed. Could you help me please?

```
<?php
include "config.php";

// Session
if(!isset($_SESSION['uname'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
}
// Logout
if(isset($_POST['but_logout'])){
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: login.php');
}
// CHECK THIS
$sql_query = "select * from users where username='".$uname."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' action="">
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            <div>
                <!-- CHECK THIS -->
                <h2>Hello <?php echo $row['name']; ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Logout" name="but_logout">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The login, logout and session are already working.
The table structure contains a table named users with the columns: id, username, password, name, email.

Thanks

Comment: You should start the session on each page referencing session variables.
So put `session_start();` at the top of the page. Any change?

Comment: And assign `$uname = $_SESSION['uname'];` before the sql statement. Any change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$uname` is undefinded

Try: `$_SESSION['uname']` on line 14;

Alway u can debug this e.g. var_dump($sql_query) and execute it in phpmyadmin

And if you want use `$row['name']`, you must have assoc array: `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`

Answer (score 0):

this is a very basic example:
first of all you must to open a conection to your server and database, create a php file, lets call "CONEXION_DB.php" and add the next code:

```
<?php
    function ConexionDBServer($DB_Con)
    {
        $servername = "your_server";
        $username = "your_user";
        $password = "your_password";

        $conDB = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
        if (!$conDB)
        {        
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
            return -1;
        }
        $DB = mysqli_select_db($conDB, $DB_Con);
        if (!$DB)
        {
            echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>
                    alert('CONEXION WITH DB FAIL');
                </SCRIPT>";
            return -1;
        }
        return $conDB;
    }
?>
```

now create your "main" page, lets call "main_page.php", and add:

```
<?php
    echo "example mysql </br>";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF?>" method="POST">  
            <input size=10 maxlength="150" type="text" name="txtUsuario">  
            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="cmdLogin">
        </form>
        <?php
            if($_POST[txtUsuario])
            {
                $sql_query = "select * from users where username='" . $_POST[txtUsuario] . "'";
                require_once('CONEXION_DB.php');
                $con=ConexionDBServer("name_of_your_db");
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo $row['username'] . "</br>";
                }
                mysqli_close($con);
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

as you can see, in order to capture the input entry from your form, you must to use the $_POST method.